# How to write NSString in a float format?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In My app I have a `UITextField`. When a user enters text such as `123456` it should appear something like `123,456.00` in the textfield.

The following code is used:

```
UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 120+y*58, 280, 31)];
txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
txt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
txt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
txt.delegate = self;
[txt addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
    NSString *textFieldText = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:textFieldText];
    NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];

    theTextField.text=formattedOutput;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: when i enter 123456 i just get 123,456 as a text ........i want the text should be display in 123,456.00.

Comment: Update your number formatter to use the desired number of fractional digits.

Comment: plz can u show me how to update....?

Comment: Read the docs for `NSNumberFormatter`. It should be clear what methods you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost close to your solution just few things need enhancement. First you must have to specify the maximum and minimum allowed fractions digits like this:

```
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

It will fix the `*.00` problem, then there is another problem of updating it back to the UI. Since you are setting the textfield text:

```
 theTextField.text=formattedOutput;
```

It will lose the current position of editing and hence you will lose the ground. e.g.,

You typed `1`, the above code will update the textfield with `1.00` and the cursor will move to position 5:

> 1.00
>
> ^^^^**^**

If you will edit further you won't get the expected result (the text will try to append at the end).

To fix this either you should update the text field when you finish editing using the handler `textFieldDidEndEditing` or you should use some other control like `UILabel` to display the formatted result.

**Sample Code:** (for demo)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    UITextField *txt = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 120+(3)*58, 280, 31)];
    txt.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad;
    txt.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    txt.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
    txt.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    txt.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDefault;
    txt.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:txt];
    [txt addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    
     lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 160+(3)*58, 280, 31)];
    [self.view addSubview:lbl];
}

-(void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)theTextField
{
     NSString *textFieldText = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];

     NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
    
     NSNumber *number = [formatter numberFromString:textFieldText];
     NSString *formattedOutput = [formatter stringFromNumber:number];
    
    [lbl setText:formattedOutput];
}
```

Comment: i had used textFieldDidEndEditing......for setting the text on the textField.....Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
NSString *textFieldText = theTextField.text ;

float f = [theString floatValue];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:@(f)]);
```

Set MinimumFractionDigits to 2 & MaximumFractionDigits to 2.Try above code in textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method of textfield.

Comment: No this does,nt work........when I enter 1 it shows 11.0 nd when i am trying to update the text....it does n't allow

Comment: No need to set the locale to the current locale. That is the default.

Comment: try wrirting above code in textFieldDidEndEditing delegate method of textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can set text like this to your textview.

```
theTextField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.02f", floatVal];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just use `%.2f`. No need for the `0`.

Comment: tried that earlier but that doesn't work.....ones i enter the value it does n't allow me to update it

Comment: You did not need to addTarget method. Instead of, you can use - **(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string** method.

Answer (score 0):

If you add these two lines to the code snippet you posted:

```
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

right after the line in which you set the number formatter's style to NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle, it should give you exactly what you want.

@"123456" would result in @"123,456.00"
and @"1" would result in @"1.00"